# how to say "to go viral"?

Tags: перевод

I can see from an internet search that виральный (edit: вирусный) has the meaning of "viral", but what is the translation of the phrase "*to go* viral", e.g., "that video has gone viral"?

Comment: go viral — ► to become very popular very quickly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the word `вирусный`. There are Russian expressions like `вирусный маркетинг`, `вирусная реклама`, `вирусное видео`.

> That video has gone viral. - Это видео стало вирусным. / Это видео превратилось в вирусное.

The English [Wiki article on viral marketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_marketing) has a [counterpart in the Russian Wiki called "Вирусный маркетинг"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).

This marketing-related meaning of the Russian word `вирусный` is quite new, but quite established and widely used.

Comment: I saw pages on вирусный маркетинг, but I wasn't sure what the correct way to say "go (viral)" is.

Comment: I would not understand this meaning. If I heard something like that I would think the video became infected by a computer virus or the like.

Answer (score 5):

To say `"to go viral"` within the meaning of something became widely known, popular, spreading from one to another, you can use the set phrase:

> `That video has gone viral. -- Видеоролик пошёл в народ.`

or similar idiom:

> `That video has gone viral. -- Это видео пошло в массы`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also hear "Это видео разошлось" or variants like that. As for me, I would not say "Это видео превратилось в вирусное".

Answer (score 1):

I think I've heard people sometimes use the expression "сарафанное радио" as a synonym for viral marketing -- though I think the expression predates viral marketing (and originally meant something closer to "hearsay" or "word of mouth").